# How to select a random element from ten arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have 10 arrays of type `String[]`. From these 10 arrays I want to select 1 string randomly. 
So far I've created the following:

```
static final String[] puzzle1 = new String[] {"1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "?" };
static final String[] puzzle2 = new String[] { "1" , "3" , "5" , "7" , "?"};
static final String[] puzzle3 = new String[] { "1" , "3" , "5" , "7" , "?"};
static final String[] puzzle4 = new String[] { "1" , "3" , "5" , "7" , "?"};
static final String[] puzzle5 = new String[] { "1" , "3" , "5" , "7" , "?"};


static final String[] select = new String[] { "puzzle1" , "puzzle2" , "puzzle3" ,
    "puzzle4" , "puzzle5"};

Random rand = new Random();
int selectedString = rand.nextInt(select.length);   
String selectedPuzzle = select[selectedString];
```

This allows me to select an array name. But how do I get the array values?

Comment: added same question again???

Comment: i got stuck at this point sir.please help me

Answer (score 2):

> From these 10 arrays I want to select 1 string randomly.

You just need to select a random array, then a random element from that array. The trick is to store an array or arrays, rather than an array of array names.

```
static final String[] puzzle1 = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "?" };
static final String[] puzzle2 = { "1", "3", "5", "7", "?" };
static final String[] puzzle3 = { "1", "3", "5", "7", "?" };
static final String[] puzzle4 = { "1", "3", "5", "7", "?" };
static final String[] puzzle5 = { "1", "3", "5", "7", "?" };

static final String[][] allPuzzles = { puzzle1, puzzle2, puzzle3, puzzle4,
    puzzle5 };


public static String chooseRandomString() {
  Random rand = new Random();    
  String[] selectedPuzzle = allPuzzles[rand.nextInt(allPuzzles.length)];
  return selectedPuzzle[rand.nextInt(selectedPuzzle.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is

```
String thirdElementOfPuzzle2 = select[2];
```

but basically what your `select` is pointing at is wrong

```
String [] select;

switch (selectedString ) {
     case :0
         select = puzzle1;
         break;
     case 1:
         select = puzzle2;

     //etc
```

At the moment

```
String selectedPuzzle = select[selectedString];
```

All you are getting is the `name` of the puzzle.  Unless you use reflection, you can not access the array using the name dynamically, so you have to do a equality test e.g. if I choose number 0 then give me the first puzzle, if I choose 1 give me the second puzzle etc.  Then you can assign the chosen puzzle to a generic array which can then be referenced later in your code.

Comment: sorry sir i am not able to understand.i think you got my answer so please explain more sir

Comment: There is no need to use a `switch` statement for this problem. Just use a `String[][]`.

Comment: `static final String[][] allPuzzles = new String[][] { puzzle1, puzzle2, puzzle3,
    puzzle4, puzzle5};` is good

Answer (score 0):

Change the Select array to two dimensional `String[][]`

put the all the array inside the  `select[][]`

get the value randomly from the randomly selected array

```
public static void main(String args[]){

         final String[] puzzle1 = new String[] {"1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "?" };
         final String[] puzzle2 = new String[] { "1" , "3" , "5" , "7" , "?"};
         final String[] puzzle3 = new String[] { "1" , "3" , "5" , "7" , "?"};
         final String[] puzzle4 = new String[] { "1" , "3" , "5" , "7" , "?"};
         final String[] puzzle5 = new String[] { "1" , "3" , "5" , "7" , "?"};


         final String[][] select = new String[][] { puzzle1 , puzzle2 , puzzle3 , puzzle4 , puzzle5};

                    Random rand = new Random();
            int selectedString = rand.nextInt(select.length);   
            String selectedPuzzle = select[selectedString][selectedString];
            System.out.print(selectedPuzzle );

    }
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/7nTbAF)</kbd>

Comment: Note that this solution will only work when the number of puzzles matches exactly to the number of strings within a puzzle. A better option is to select two random numbers, one based on `select.length` and one based on `selectedPuzzle.length`.